# How can I use Animated switcher without a button in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have multiple widgets I want to fade in one after another but without needing a button. Every tutorial I have seen has required the use of a button in order to transition to the next widget. The widgets I want to transition take up the whole screen .

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to trigger the transition?

*If time is a suitable trigger.*

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  late Timer timer;
  int count = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => setState(() => count += 1));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
              return ScaleTransition(child: child, scale: animation);
            },
            child: Text(
              '$count',
              key: ValueKey<int>(count),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want each animation to trigger right after another, so like 1 screen's fade transition duration takes .4 seconds and stays on the screen for 1 second then the next screen starts with same parameters. (Each Screen displaying a widget with text)